# Unable to add a number to a variable (New to Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

still reasonably new to Unity and c# and so this may be a small and insignificant question to some but it has stumped me. I'm trying to add a number to my score when a game object is destroyed, I have a target script attached to a target prefab.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;
    private float TotalCubesHit = 0;

    public void TakeDamage (float amount){

        health = health - (amount);

        if (health <= 0f) {
            TotalCubesHit += 1;
            Die(); 
        }
    }

    public void Die()
    {

        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log(TotalCubesHit);
    }
}
```

For some reason, it never gets above one and I'm unsure as to why? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use a [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) counter. This makes it a class field which is "shared" among all instances or better said is simply not bound to any instance:

```
public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;

    private static float totalCubesHit = 0;
    // Optionally add a public ReadOnly property 
    // for allowing external access
    public static float TotalCubesHit => totalCubesHit;

    public void TakeDamage (float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;

        if (health <= 0f) 
        {
            totalCubesHit++;
            Die(); 
        }
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log(totalCubesHit);
    }
}
```

A useful side-effect (and therefore I added the public ReadOnly [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)): You can now also access it from any other script by simply using

```
Target.TotalCubeHits
```

while being sure it can not be changed by other scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It is because it is incremented only once .. thats right before it dies.

```cs
public void TakeDamage (float amount){

        health = health - (amount);
        TotalCubesHit += 1;   // <-- Move that outside of the if statement
        if (health <= 0f) {

            Die(); 
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: I have been re-reading your question and one thing i dont quite follow is: "I'm trying to add a number to my score when a game object is destroyed". 
 If your intent is to keep track of the totalCubeHits from different Target objects that are destroyed, this wont work unless you are re-using the same Target object. If you create a new instance each time, TotalCubeHits will always start from 0.

Store the TotalCubeHits outside or initialize it with a number from previous object.